How to permanently set an environment variable avaialble to a snap app?
Is there a way to permanently set environment variables for a particular snap app, or for all snap apps?
I want to start my snap app with a particular environment variable without having to start it from the terminal. I could edit the app start script, but then if the app updates, I would need to do it again.
I'm looking for some equivalente of /etc/environment for snap.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want the variable to be available only when the snap application starts, you will need, just like you need to do for a regular application, adapt the start script or the .desktop launcher. However, you can do so in a separate copy that takes precedence over the system installed script or .desktop launcher.

Add an environmental variable through the .desktop launcher

Copy the launcher to ~/.local/share/applications if the change is required for the current user only, to /usr/local/share/applications if the change is to affect all users of the system
Edit the Exec= line to add the environmental variable, e.g. Exec=env Mynewvariable=Value firefox


Work with a wrapper script

Create a wrapper script with the same name as the executable of the application, and place it in ~/.local/bin if the change is required for the current user only, or in /usr/local/bin if the change is to affect all users. These paths come earlier in the PATH, so executables will override system installed executables with the same name.
This will work only if no path is coded on the Exec= line in the .desktop launcher, which commonly is the case for software installed using the Software Store. If a path is coded, you also will need to override the .desktop launcher so it points to the desired executable.




Thanks! However, I was looking for something more snap-supported rather than a workaround. Doing that works fine as long as the .desktop file doesn't get updated (like new arguments in the exec line or new icon).

This is not a workaround. It works the same for applications installed as APT. IF the developper of the package does not implement something like that, the user can. Please consider accepting this answer if it answered your question.

It's not a permanent solution as updates will override the .desktop file. One example of permanent solution for APT is adding the env to /etc/environment, like I mentioned in the original question.


It is a permanent solution that will not be overwritten; 2) It is definitely the better approach if the variable is needed by a single or few application only. However, it is not a good solution if the variable should be available for multiple applications: there I agree with you.

